# Substraction in MYSQL with some condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to do SUM and SUBTRACTION upon certain condition within mysql query

i have try like this,
asuming the `$balance`= 655.000.000 then total amount inside `my_table` = IDR 80.000.000 and USD 500.000

```
$currency_id = 1;
$balance = 655.000.000;
DB::table('my_table as a')
    ->join('master_currencies as b', 'a.master_currency_id', 'b.id')
    ->where('a.id', $id)
    ->selectRaw("SUM(
         CASE
             WHEN $currency_id = a.master_currency_id THEN $balance - a.amount
         ELSE
             a.amount
         END) AS net_value, b.symbol, b.id as master_currency_id"
         )
         ->groupBy('b.id')
         ->get();
```

The code above should give the result

```
[
  {"net_value":"575.000.000","symbol":"IDR","master_currency_id":1},
  {"net_value":"500.000","symbol":"USD","master_currency_id":2}
]
```

but the result i got is

```
[
  {"net_value":"1.885.000.000","symbol":"IDR","master_currency_id":1},
  {"net_value":"500.000","symbol":"USD","master_currency_id":2}
]
```

**Note:**
Please ignore dots between numbers, in my database i'm not using these dots. it is for inquiry purposes only

Answer (score -1):

If you have more than one row of IDR then it might be a problem with order of operations.

For example say you have to values (100.000.000) and (50.000.000) then for IDR SUM(655.000.000-100.000.000, 655.000.000-50.000.000)=1.160.000.000 and is not the same as 655.000.000-SUM(100.000.000,50.000.000)=505.000.000 the problem being that each row in the group that you aggregate gets a clean `$balance`.

You could potentially solve this by doing:

```
$currency_id = 1;
$balance = 655.000.000;
DB::table('my_table as a')
    ->join('master_currencies as b', 'a.master_currency_id', 'b.id')
    ->where('a.id', $id)
    ->selectRaw("
         (CASE 
            WHEN a.id=$currency_id $balance-SUM(a.amount)
         ELSE
            SUM(a.amount)  
         END) AS net_value, b.symbol, b.id as master_currency_id")
         ->groupBy('b.id')
         ->get();
```